# Simon game mechanism (Javascript) -- Sequence input

Tags: javascript, jquery, sequence

Essentially I have the following:

1) Game will randomly pre-choose 20 random sequence

2) Game will turn off click event listener

3) Game will display the light sequence for each level(starting level 1)

4) Game will turn on click event listener so that user can input via .buttons

5) Game will evaluate user's input

I am having trouble on the 5th step...

How do evaluate user's input while the game is still running? I thought about using while loop but it seems that doesn't work quite nicely...

```
Board.prototype.getUserInput = function(){
    board.userInput = []; //reset the user input
    $(".button").click(function(){
       var currentLevel = board.sequence.slice(0,board.index);
       var color = $(this).attr('id');
       board.userInput.push(color)
       board.evaluateInput(currentLevel);
})
```

}

heres my codepen: http://codepen.io/neotriz/pen/RRxOJb

Comment: On step 1, push your random sequence to a new array. On step 5, compare the users input to the relevant index of that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old implementation i had done of the game.
http://codepen.io/antoniskamamis/pen/pJAxq?editors=0010#0

Basically since you have predefined the order all you have to do is increase a counter with each click on a color and check if the color clicked is the one in the nth position of your predefined colors

pseudocode for the solution

```
var predefinedColors = ['red', 'yellow',...]
var turn = 0;
buttons.addEventListener("click", ev => {
  if(ev.target.classList.contain(predefinedColors[turn]){
    //right guess
    turn++
  } else {
   // wrong guess reset game
  }

})
```

Comment: That totally makes sense: theres no reason to have an array of user's input. Just keep it simple :)